# Steps to setup Grails -code-coverage plugin with Jenkins CI?

Tags: code-coverage, grails-plugin, jenkins-plugins

Has any one got setup Grails -code-coverage plugin with Jenkins CI?

If so please walk me through the setup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this tutorial: [code coverage](http://leanjavaengineering.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/grails-testing-in-hudson/)